# How to set column values justify right in isqlplus

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I want to set my column values to the right aligned..

Comment: Do you work on oracle? isql it isn't oracle.

Comment: You need to add more information to your question in order to get help.  Code examples, data examples, output examples. etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
column colum_name justify right
```

You can also use lpad:

```
select lpad('AAA', 7) from dual
```

Comment: I tried this but it is not working, remember my values are varchar.